# What is the significance of cigarettes in ashtray at opening and closing credits of “The Big Sleep?”

Tags: analysis, credits, the-big-sleep

In *The Big Sleep* (1946), while I find cigarettes in ashtray.

Opening credits:

[image]

Closing credits:

[image]

What is the significance of cigarettes in ashtray at opening and closing credits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer would be "because it's noir and it looks good". (And I think it's the right answer).

The more complex would be something like waves and smoke in the beginning and end in the *[Death in Venice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_in_Venice_(film))* (1971) so it’s a sign of mortality and fragile of human life that can be easily put out like a cigarette.

Two cigarettes are a sign of the human relations where two individuals can burn next o each other started with the same match (passion) which end in demise of them both.